# How to specify a string value from a returned database returned tuple

Tags: python, sqlite, tuples

When running the following code I would like to be able to store the returned values in a variable as a string. However when I run the code it will return the first name from the database in this format

```
[(u'Kiefer',)]
```

What would I need to change in order to just return a clean string? I was thinking I could use strip although I have never used it on a tuple (not even sure if you can) but I was hoping there is a more elegant way. Also I am using the sqlite3 module.

```
def search_db(self,ID,FName,LName):
    #try:
    FName +='%'
    LName += '%'
    self.cur.execute(("""SELECT FirstName FROM members WHERE FirstName LIKE '%s'\
    AND LastName LIKE '%s'""") % (FName, LName))
    value = (self.cur.fetchall())
    print(value)
    #except:
        #print('failed')


cla = Database()
cla.search_db(1,'K','D')
```

Comment: `value[0][0]` is your string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the first element of the list, which is the tuple, then the first element of the tuple, so:

```
value[0][0]
```